# Restrict height of CSS table - ignore content height

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am having trouble with a CSS table I am using for layout.  Not a traditional table but a set of div's using `display:table` etc.

The problem is that it works great when one of the cell div's is empty, however as soon as I add content to it, the table stretches to accommodate the content.

```css
#dispcontainer {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.disprow  {
    display: table-row;
    width:100%;
}

.dispcell {
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

The HTMl:

```
<body>

<div class="box">
<div class="content">
<div id="dispcontainer">
    <div class="disprow">
        <div class="dispcell">
        <img class="heading_img" src="img/heading.png" /><br />
        <div class="nav_buttons">
        <?php include("menu.html"); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="disprow">
        <div class="dispcell">
            <div style="height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
            <?php include("tumblr/tumblrFeed.php"); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
        <?php include("social_buttons.html"); ?>
</div>

<div id="contactBar"><?php include("contactDetails.html")?></div>
</body>
```

And the website proper is here: http://fadeinfuture.net/users/tbw/test2.php

I just don't understand how to get the table to never become taller than it's containing div.

I got it working with regular `<table>`'s, however Internet Explorer didn't like it basically with the same problem.

The reason for this layout is that I want the heading to be fluid depending on the screen width and the area below to take up the rest of the screen.

Comment: How do you want to deal with content that overflows out of any fixed height table cell?

Comment: overflow:scroll or hidden which i would have thought would have worked.  the problem is that the content in the div is forcing the div to be a certain height thus no overflow.  I have tried overflow but it never happens as the content makes the div ignore the height:100% attribute.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: There is a conceptual problem with the layout geometry.  You have two table rows, and within each, you want the cell to be 100% of the view port height.  Therefore, the table will be 200% in total height.  Is this really what you want?

Comment: no but what i want is the top row's height to be controlled by the image inside it's height (which is based on the width of the window) and then the bottom row's height to be whatever is left of the div.  it's a great point you make point, i have removed height 100% from the disprow class but if i make the bottom row 100% it will be too large.

Comment: If you pick the right image dimensions, you can make the image fill up the top row with a height of 100%, and then you have no room for any content in your second row.  So how do you want to deal with that scenario? Put a max height on the image in the first row might be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your `overflow-y: scroll;` to the `box` div.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript and jQuery. (with pure css it MAY BE more difficult)

```
<script>
   $(function() {
      $("#parent").height($("#child").height());
   });
</script>
```

I use something like that on my website.